# Get path to Silverlight ClientBin directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to get the path to the ClientBin directory from within my .Web project inside a Silverlight application. Currently, my method looks like this, but there has to be a better/more concise way to get this path:

```
public static string GetClientBinPath()
{
   var applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

   if (applicationPath.StartsWith(@"file:\"))
      applicationPath = applicationPath.Remove(0, 6);

   applicationPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, @"..\ClientBin");

   return applicationPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Web project you should use the static method [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) of the HostingEnvironment class.

```
string pathToClientBin = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ClientBin");
```

The class is located in the System.Web.Hosting namespace of the assembly System.Web

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the quick response. I knew there had to be an easier way to "map" virtual space to physical space.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old but here you go:

```
currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.Current.Host.Source.LocalPath);
```

It works for out of the browser application. I haven't test it in the browser.